# AnyLogic creating a deterministic order of railcars in a train

Tags: anylogic

I'm creating a train using the Rail Pallette. I've created a train agent and several different types of Rail Car agents. I've gone through the [Hump Yard Tutorial](https://www.anylogic.help/tutorials/rail/3-creating-rail-car-types.html); this details how to create a randomly generated train with several types of rail cars.

I need to create a train with several different rail cars in a deterministic order. I imagine a `createUniform()` function that takes the classes and creates the cars in the order given until the train length is reached.

I've tried several different avenues. The closest is creating my own `createUniform()` function, but I am not able to return the different car types as their classes don't match. I've attempted to have it return `Agent` but this still results in an error: `cannot cast OpenCar to Agent`.

Is there a way to create a parent class for all my cars so that they can be returned from one function?

Comment: Sure you can, as described in the help: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/inheritance.html

Comment: @mczandrea I just tried extending all my car classes from a `RailCar` class. This did not allow the function to return different types of cars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the TrainSource block, under the New rail car section you can switch to code instead of the agent picker. They provide you with a `carindex` parameters, which you can use to define the car. This can be used with the ternary operator if you don't want to write an special function.

For example:

```
(carindex < 2)?
  new Locomotive() :
  (carindex < 10) :
    new HopperCar() :
    new ContainerCar()
```

In this case, the first two cars (`carindex` 0 and 1) will be Locomotives, then `carindex` 2 to 9 will be HopperCars, and 10 onwards will be ContainerCars.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this solution is much more elegant than mine. I'm not super familiar with Java, but the syntax makes sense now that I see it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a type of car in the function I created an `Agent` object, set that equal to my car object, then returned that `Agent` object.

```
Agent newCar = null;
newCar = new CustomerCarClass();
return newCar;
```

This allows me to set the custom function as returning an `Agent` object.